# Union two rectangles in Java OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, operator-overloading

[This documentation page](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Rect.html) states:

> In addition to the class members, the following operations on
>   rectangles are implemented:
>   [...]
>
> - rect = rect1 | rect2 (minimum area rectangle containing rect2 and rect3)

However, this code:

```
Rect box1 = new Rect();
Rect box2 = new Rect();
Rect unionBox = new Rect();

unionBox = box1 | box2;
```

leads to this error:

> Operator '|' cannot be applied to 'org.opencv.core.Rect', 'org.opencv.core.Rect'

How do I correctly union two (or better: many) `Rect`s?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK using operators is not supported on JAVA.

i suggest using [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#boundingRect-org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint-) but you should to know there is one pixel difference as seen C++ code below

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Rect a(10,10,20,20);
    Rect b(11,11,20,20);

    vector<Point> pts;

    pts.push_back(a.tl());
    pts.push_back(a.br());

    pts.push_back(b.tl());
    pts.push_back(b.br());

    Rect boundingRect_result = boundingRect( pts );
    Rect operator_result = a | b;

    cout << "Rect a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "Rect b: " << b << endl;

    cout << "\nRect Points a b:\n" << pts << endl;

    cout << "\nboundingRect result : " << boundingRect_result << endl;
    cout << "result a | b        : " << operator_result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
Rect a: [20 x 20 from (10, 10)]
Rect b: [20 x 20 from (11, 11)]

Rect Points a b:
[10, 10;
 30, 30;
 11, 11;
 31, 31]

boundingRect result : [22 x 22 from (10, 10)]
result a | b        : [21 x 21 from (10, 10)]
```

(i am not familiar with JAVA but tried to write the code below to test)

```
Rect r1 = new Rect(10,10,20,20);
Rect r2 = new Rect(11,11,20,20);

Point[] rects_pts = new Point[4];
rects_pts[0] =  r1.tl();
rects_pts[1] =  r1.br();
rects_pts[2] =  r2.tl();
rects_pts[3] =  r2.br();

MatOfPoint mof = new MatOfPoint();
mof.fromArray(rects_pts);

Rect union = Imgproc.boundingRect(mof);
System.out.print( union);
```

result is like `{10, 10, 22x22}`

another option is writing your own function in JAVA. [here is OpenCV source](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp#L1779-L1789) that can be converted to JAVA